# Is it possible to add a regression/fitted line equation to a mixed-effect model plot?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution

I have been asked to add a regression/fitted line equation to a negative binomial mixed effect model plot. Example of a regression line equation is highlighted in yellow below for `linear` model.

[image]

I searched papers online, I didn't see a regression line equation for a negative binomial mixed effect model plot. Can someone provide insights or guidance on how can we add a regression line to a mixed effect model plot? Alternatively, if there is any indication that this approach might not be feasible or desirable for this model type, a reference or explanation would be highly appreciated.
My model

```
model <- glmmTMB(total_count ~ mean_temp*lwd_duration + (1|year), family = nbinom1, data=df)

summary(model)

Family: nbinom1  ( log )
Formula:          total_count ~ mean_temp * lwd_duration + (1 | year)
Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   260.6    270.7   -124.3    248.6       34 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 year   (Intercept) 3.683e-09 6.069e-05
Number of obs: 40, groups:  year, 4

Dispersion parameter for nbinom1 family ():  178 

Conditional model:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)             9.609769   3.276724   2.933  0.00336 **
mean_temp              -0.341435   0.177426  -1.924  0.05431 . 
lwd_duration           -0.105528   0.039145  -2.696  0.00702 **
mean_temp:lwd_duration  0.005819   0.002078   2.801  0.00510 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My plot

```
pred_df <- expand.grid(mean_temp = seq(10, 25, len = 100),
                       lwd_duration = seq(10, 200, 0.1),
                       year = factor(2017, 2017:2014))

pred_df$total_count <- predict(model, newdata = pred_df, type = "response")

ggplot(pred_df, aes(mean_temp, total_count, color = lwd_duration,
                    group = lwd_duration)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(df$total_count), xlim = range(df$mean_temp)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 22)
```

[image]

Reproducible example

```
df <- structure(list(year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                        4L), levels = c("2017", "2016", "2015", "2014"), class = "factor"), 
                     mean_temp = c(10.31, 10.31, 11.35, 11.35, 14.05, 14.05, 15.96, 
                                   15.96, 16.73, 16.73, 20.92, 20.92, 21.89, 21.89, 21.48, 21.48, 
                                   25.82, 25.82, 21.06, 21.06, 16.3, 16.3, 20.16, 20.16, 19.85, 
                                   19.85, 25.45, 25.45, 24.32, 24.32, 20.59, 20.78, 20.78, 20.78, 
                                   22.23, 22.23, 22.23, 19.71, 19.71, 19.71), lwd_duration = c(116.53, 
                                                                                               116.53, 146.18, 146.18, 184.48, 184.48, 67.3, 67.3, 70.08, 
                                                                                               70.08, 71.43, 71.43, 68.58, 68.58, 91.6, 91.6, 72.07, 72.07, 
                                                                                               59.57, 59.57, 13.02, 13.02, 75.33, 75.33, 60.07, 60.07, 98.08, 
                                                                                               98.08, 71.78, 71.78, 40.25, 54.5, 54.5, 54.5, 32.47, 32.47, 
                                                                                               32.47, 61.73, 61.73, 61.73), total_count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                            0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                            0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 362L, 135L, 684L, 34L, 123L, 21L, 
                                                                                                                                            6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 13L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                       year = structure(1:4, levels = c("2017", "2016", "2015", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "2014"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:10, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           11:20, 21:30, 31:40), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data. Frame")))
```

Comment: Mmh? It is not clear if you want to plot model predictions or the model equation with parameter estimates. You have two continuous predictors. There is no single regression line that could be plotted. You should probably start with reviewing the mathematical formulation of a GLM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Overview

Comment: @Roland That's what I think too. I visited Google Scholar and checked negative binomial glmms, not a single paper has reported fitted line equation. I have been asked to do this by someone who doesn't understand multivariate regression. I am not expert myself. Came to stack for some valid `reason/reference` to convince him that it's not possible.